# Asynchronous decorator for both generators and coroutines

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio, python-decorators

This question related to the same question in a [synchronous version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53687459/1720199).
The goal is to design decorator that would take as input either a generator or a coroutine as parameter. The code I have looks like:

```
import asyncio


def say_hello(function):

    async def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        return_value = function(*args, **kwargs)
        if isinstance(return_value, types.AsyncGeneratorType):
            print("Hello async generator!")
            async for v in return_value:
                yield v
        else:
            print("Hello coroutine!")
            return await return_value

    return decorated


@helpers.say_hello
async def generator():
    for i in range(5):
        await asyncio.sleep(0.2)
        yield i

@helpers.say_hello
async def coroutine():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return list(range(5))


async def test():
    for v in generator():
        print(v)
    for v in coroutine():
        print(v)
```

The error this gives is:

```
'return' with value in async generator
```

Which I guess is just checked statically on the fact that `decorated` contains both a `yield` and a `return` with a value.

Is there any way to make this work? (Other than having a parameter in `say_hello` to specify if `function` is a generator or a coroutine).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can basically use the same mechanism deployed by the other answer, but applied for coroutines. For example:

```
def say_hello(function):
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        function_instance = function(*args, **kwargs)
        if isinstance(function_instance, types.AsyncGeneratorType):
            async def inner():
                print("Hello async generator!")
                async for v in function_instance:
                    yield v
        else:
            async def inner():
                print("Hello coroutine!")
                return await function_instance
        return inner()
    return decorated
```

Note that in this case `decorated` is defined using `def` rather than `async def`. This ensures that, when called, it immediately starts running and is able to choose what to return, an async generator-iterator on a coroutine object. Since `decorated` *returns* an object created by calling a function defined with `async def inner`, it is functionally equivalent to being `async def` itself.

Your `test` function is incorrect because it uses `for` to iterate over an async generator, and it iterates over the coroutine. Instead, it should be `async def` and use `async for` to iterate over the async generator and `await` to await the coroutine. I used the following code to test (`generator` and `coroutine` are unchanged):

```
async def test():
    async for v in generator():
        print(v)
    await coroutine()

asyncio.run(test())
# or, on Python 3.6 and older:
#asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(test())
```

Comment: Great! Another option is to use `inspect.isasyncgenfunction(function)` instead of the `isinstance(function_instance, types.AsyncGeneratorType)`.

Comment: You saved me a lot of pain and suffering, thank you!